# I got a problem with my Ultrasonic HC-SR04

Tags: arduino, arduino-ultra-sonic

this is the error

```
Tone.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `timer0_pin_port':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_7'
C:\Users\ana98\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_633619\libraries\NewPing\NewPing.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Using library NewPing at version 1.9.7 in folder: C:\Users\ana98\OneDrive\Documentos\Arduino\libraries\NewPing 
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.
```

My expectations where simple, just a code with a buzzer that tones up if something appears in fornt of the ultraonic sensor
Just a simple code

```
#include <NewPing.h>

#define TRIGGER_PIN  13 // Pin digital para el trigger del sensor ultrasónico (puede ser cualquier pin digital)
#define ECHO_PIN     12  // Pin digital para el echo del sensor ultrasónico (puede ser cualquier pin digital)
#define BUZZER_PIN   4   // Pin digital para el zumbador (puede ser cualquier pin digital)

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, 200);  // Inicializar el sensor ultrasónico con una distancia máxima de 200 cm

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUZZER_PIN, OUTPUT);  // Configurar el pin del zumbador como salida
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);  // Pequeña pausa para estabilidad
  unsigned int distance = sonar.ping_cm();  // Medir la distancia en centímetros

  if (distance < 50) {
    // Si el objeto está a menos de 50 cm, hacer sonar un tono alto
    tone(BUZZER_PIN, 1000);  // Hacer sonar el zumbador a 1000Hz
  } else {
    // Si el objeto está a más de 50 cm, hacer sonar un tono bajo
    tone(BUZZER_PIN, 500);  // Hacer sonar el zumbador a 500Hz
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In newPing library header, author wrote :

```
//    Added TIMER_ENABLED switch to get around compile-time "__vector_7" errors when
//   using the Tone library, or you can use the toneAC, NewTone or
//   TimerFreeTone libraries: https://bitbucket.org/teckel12/arduino-toneac/
```

'TIMER_ENABLED' value in newPing.h seems to be plateform dependant and I suggest you to use one of the others tone's libraries as recommended : It will be much simpler and much more compatible.

for exemple newTone (https://forum.arduino.cc/t/newtone-library-plug-in-replacement-for-tone-library-better-smaller-faster/140506) :

```
#include <NewTone.h>
#include <NewPing.h>

etc...

if (distance < 50) {
    // Si el objeto está a menos de 50 cm, hacer sonar un tono alto
    newTone(BUZZER_PIN, 1000);  // Hacer sonar el zumbador a 1000Hz
  } else {
    // Si el objeto está a más de 50 cm, hacer sonar un tono bajo
    newTone(BUZZER_PIN, 500);  // Hacer sonar el zumbador a 500Hz
  }
```